# Which is a good textbook on stochastic processes which takes measure theoretic approach?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I was looking for an intermediate-advanced textbook on stochastic process. I have graduate level probability knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

1. Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales: Volume 1 by Rogers and Williams.
2. Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion by Revuz and Yor.

Answer (score 0):

Allan Gut's Graduate Course in Probability.
Sheldon Ross' Second Course in Probability.
R. M. Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability.

There may be others but I do not know them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the books of Hoel, Port and Stone.